# importing or converting files

Tags: import

I am trying to import files from an intramural scanner, which is cerec inlab 4.2. I want to test some ideas and try some addons.  the file exporting in stl format is open in more recent cerec software.  knowing cerec I can imagine they are going to ask for unbelievable amount of money to upgrade me.  the main issue is I want to try addons and I want to make a virtually designed custom made implants and splints.  I cannot think of investing a bulk while I STILL do not know will things work with me or not.   Can I import .lab files in blender.  if not how can I transfer it to stl files

Comment: After some heavy google search, I found out that CEREC produces dental printers(?) and that the .lab format is a proprietary format, which means that probably nobody is going to program an importer very soon or at all. So the only options you have is either buying the CEREC update or datakit CrossManager (around $1000) or you manage to find s.o. who owns them and is willing to export your .lab file to Wavefront .obj format. Either way, this question seems a little too localized for a better answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried to find a way myself, I have been on the search for about 13 hours now and could not find a software or a plug in to do that.  I found a plug in to rhinoceros called dental shaper to do the job.  rhino is about $1000 and I do not know the dental shaper is how much yet, but anyway it would be a very expensive way to see if I am going to succeed in my thoughts or not.  hopefully I find a plug in in blender (I think I will not find at least now) but I really appreciate your effort and time trying to help me.  Sincerely Yours Ahmed Barakat